# jquery Datatable not sorting properly

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I am not getting correct sorting result in jquery Datatable . i tried by changeing table collection type in database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG1bN.png)

Answer (score 2):

maybe a space before the text that screws up the sorting?
you will have to give us more then this for a solution tho

- https://codepen.io/ example code or

  - a bit of the code that is printed
- any error in the console?
- is it sorting correctly in the database?